# Sum diffrent number of rows in same colum

Tags: excel-formula

please someone help to to sum different number of rows in single column in minimum key stroke.

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by different number of rows ? do you want to get the sum of the values in Bold ?

Comment: Yes, I need there sum value

Comment: I need to sum in blue cells & each sum will have different ranges like in first blue cells has 3 cells above to sum & second blue cell has only 1 cell to sum. hence may be third blue cell would have only 2 cells to sum & another may have X cells.
I think Now I could explain my need.
THANKS FOR HELP.

Comment: You can add a function in column G which checks if cells in column F is BOLD, return true or False https://trumpexcel.com/filter-bold-font-formatting-in-excel/, then replace True by 1 and false by 0 in column H, then make the sum of column F * Column H which will return only cells which are in BOLD: see my answer edited

Answer (score 0):

You can change the position of the cells a little.

You can create a column with totals for every section. Then you can use the usual function sum to calculate all result of the column "Sum of quantity".

[Proposal example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDgDv.png)

Comment: Thank your help ! but is there not any way so that I will select all colored cells & put a formula & press ctrl+enter or use auto sum button.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a function in column G which checks if cells in column F is BOLD:

return true or False

[How to Filter Cells with Bold Font Formatting in Excel (An Easy Guide)](https://trumpexcel.com/filter-bold-font-formatting-in-excel/)

then replace True by 1 and false by 0 in column H

then make the sum of column F * Column H which will return only cells which are in BOLD